# Windows + R (run) command to open Network Connections dialog

Tags: networking, shortcuts

Find myself constantly changing NIC properties every day (switch, router, etc. config).  Any happy fun command to open this dialog (.cpl or .msc) from the Run dialog?

Answer (score 40):

`ncpa.cpl` will open up the **Network Connections** window.

Or you can create a Shortcut to:
`C:\Windows\System32\control.exe ncpa.cpl`

*[Official MS List](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/192806) of `.cpl` commands to access a number of Control Panel tools.*

Comment: Definitely a good one to pin to the Start Menu. You have to set `'control.exe ncpa.cpl'` as the target. If you try to use just `'ncpa.cpl'` it will only let you pin it to Settings, which is lame.

Comment: Note, that in the referenced [*Official MS List*](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/192806), you can wrongly read `Network Properties control netcpl.cpl`first if you're not very careful. [The link on Windows run commands](http://web.archive.org/web/20160911082902/http://www.windows-commandline.com/windows-7-run-commands) 
    provided by [Sriniv](https://superuser.com/users/150120/sriniv) was a bit more useful but is archived (and not maintained) since 2017. [The source by user1686 is more useful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_Panel_(Windows)#Standard_applets).

Answer (score 10):

Try `ncpa.cpl`, [`control netconnections`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_Panel_(Windows)#Standard_applets), or `::{208d2c60-3aea-1069-a2d7-08002b30309d}`.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone else likes to also launch a particular connection within the dialog automatically, Here is a good solution.

```
"rasphone.exe -d "<connection name>"
```

One may create a shortcut to it or just use it from command line.